# Constructing a number system

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have just started working through a book on higher algebra. I'm just at the beginning, where the authors introduce the notation and talk about the various number systems.

I found this particular paragraph confusing:- "The basic idea in the construction of new set of numbers is to take a set, call it $ S $, consisting of mathematical objects, such as numbers you are already familiar with, partition the set $ S $ into a collection of sets in a suitable way, and then attach names or labels, to each of the subsets. These subsets will be elements of a new number system."

What does the author mean, when he says a "suitable way" here? Does it mean, that I can partition in any way that I find suitable, or are there requirements to be met, for any number system that is constructed by me?

For instance, I'm familiar with the set of natural numbers. So, can I construct $S= ${$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$} and call it a subset of a new number system? Can I go as far as to say that this subset is the only element of my new number system?

Comment: It might be useful to know if you're familiar with the concept of [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). Are you?

Comment: Though I haven't reached that in the book yet, the Wikipedia link makes it clear. Yes, I think I understand what the three properties  of reflexivity, symmetricity and transitivity are, and any relation on a set which satisfies those three properties is called an equivalence relation. Please go ahead with your explanation.

Comment: Other people already covered that.I was in the process of writing an aswer, but there's no point anymore. I'll just leave you with the first part of my answer as a comment.

Comment: `What does the author mean, when he says a "suitable way" here? Does it mean, that I can partition in any way that I find suitable, or are there requirements to be met, for any number system that is constructed by me?`

Usually there are some requirements in mind, not unmotivated requirements though. You partition a set in such a way that you get a formalization of some intuitive concept you have in mind. 

For instance the rational numbers, $\Bbb Q$, **can be interpreted** as being the set $\left\{\dfrac{p}{q}:(p,q)\in \Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}\right\}$.

Comment: So it looks like the rational numbers can be built from the integers. (Now I suggest you move on to the answers).

Comment: Thank you Git Gud. From your comments and the answers below, I think I understand it all now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an example would help. We're all familiar with the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$. Then we also have the set of ordered pairs of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. If we partition $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ using the equivalence relation $(a, b) \sim (c, d)$ when $a + d = b + c$, then this equivalence relation partitions $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ out into subsets. You can think of each subset as containing pairs $(a, b), (c, d), \dots$ where $a - b = c - d = \ldots$. So each subset can be thought of as an integer by picking any pair $(a, b)$ out of it and thinking of it as the integer $a - b$.

But this is a bit circular, since the point is that we imagine we didn't formally have the integers yet, but we had an intuition for them, and just formally constructed them from $\mathbb{N}$. We just came up with a new number system, and attached names to the subsets; for example, the subset that contains the pair $(1, 4)$ can be called $-3$.

So suitable means it fulfils some sort of intuition we have about something we think exists in a real-world sense, or at least has some abstract reality. We can come up with silly, meaningless number systems which are technically equally valid, but mean less to human beings. "Suitable" isn't a mathematical term, it's a social and psychological one.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I understand your example, except for a small part; how are there multiple subsets? Using the relation $a+b=c+d$, you partition it into one subset containing the pairs $(a,b), (c,d),...$ which satisfy $a-b=c-d=...$How are other subsets formed?

Comment: For example, one subset would be $\{(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), \ldots \}$, which represents the integer $-1$, and another subset would be $\{(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), \ldots \}$ which represents the integer $-2$. There is a subset for each integer (even the positive ones).

Comment: By the way, each of these subsets is called an equivalence class, and the equivalence relation $\sim$ I described is determining when two elements (pairs of natural numbers, in this case) belong to the same equivalence class. That's all there is to equivalence relations.

Comment: Oh, I think I get the picture now! Just one more question: Can one construct such subsets to form a new number system, without equivalence relations? Even if it might not be useful or anything, is it mathematically allowed?

Comment: Sure! I don't think there's really such thing as "mathematically allowed"; it's all a matter of what is the clearest way to do things, and what the conventions are. Another way to construct the integers is to take the set of all ordered pairs $(x, y)$, where $x$ is $0$ or $1$, and $y$ is a natural number. Then you can think of $0$ as meaning positive and $1$ as meaning negative. Of course, $+0$ and $-0$ should be the same thing, so you have to remove $-0$, or something like that. This completely works too, but mathematicians tend to prefer the equivalence relation method because it's cleaner.

Comment: I see...Thanks for helping me clear this up, ferson2020!You were a great help! :)

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

The author is attempting to informally convey the notion that many constructions of number systems begin by taking a *quotient set* of a known number system, i.e. by defining an equivalence relation on the set, which is equivalent to a partition of the set (into equivalence classes). For example, fractions are constructed as pairs of integers quotiented by the equivalence relation $(a,b) \cong (c,d) \stackrel{\rm def}\iff ad = bc,\,$ where the class of $\,(a,b),\ b\ne 0\,$ represents the fraction $\,a/b.\,$  Another well-known example is the ring of integers mod $\,n\,$ whose elements are equivalence classes $\,a + n\,\Bbb Z\,$ of the equivalence relation $\, a\equiv b\pmod n\stackrel{\rm def}\iff n\mid a-b.\,$

That the equivalence relation (or partition) is constructed in a "suitable way" means that we usually desire addtitionally that the quotient object preserves some (or all) of the *algebraic* structure of the base number systems, i.e. that the algebraic operations are inherited by the quotient object. Thus we want the integers mod $\,n\,$ to be a quotient *ring* of $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ not merely a quotient *set*, which is equivalent to desiring that the equivalence realtion be, additionally, a *congruence*, i.e. $\,a\equiv a',\ b\equiv b'\,\Rightarrow\, a+b\equiv a'+b'$ and similarly for all other ring operations.

But before studying the more complex *algebraic* quotient objects, it is wise to first study the simpler case of quotient *sets*, because they are the building blocks, or raw materials, out of which the more complex algebraic quotient structures are constructed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not exactly understand what you mean by equivalence classes (as I haven't reached it yet). But I understand the partitioning is based on equivalence relations. So basically, we find an "operation" that satisfies the conditions of an equivalence relation, to perform on the elements of a known number system, and the resulting set of numbers forms a subset of the new number system, right?

Comment: @JobinIdiculla I think you have the right idea, but I wouldn't say it forms a "subset of the new number system"; it's more that the set of subsets of the old number system forms a new number system. Maybe that's just more a matter of semantics though.

Comment: @KeyIdeas, thank you for your answer as well! Though I didn't quite understand much of the terminology that you used(rings, quotient sets, congruence), I'll learn it in the coming days and come to back to this answer.